# Joda-Time convert days to months and days

Tags: java, date, jodatime

How can I convert the number of days to number of months and days using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). For example, when I have 33 days, it should display 1 month and 2 days.

```
public static void main(String[]args) 
   {        
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

         int years = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
         int month = (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH))+1;
         int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

         DateTime startDate = new DateTime(years, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
         DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2014, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0);

         Days d = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate);

         int days = d.getDays();
         int t = 1000 * 60 * 60 *24;
         int days = days/t;
         System.out.println(days);
}
```

Comment: But different months have different days. What about February month? If you consider it as 31 days for each month then simply do it using math calculation. There is no need to sue JodaTime at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use class [**org.joda.time.Period**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) for this.
Example:

```
  Period p = new Period(startDate, endDate, PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());
  System.out.println(p.getMonths()); 
  System.out.println(p.getDays());
```

Comment: Thanks dude... worked like a charm! I Would buy you a muffin right about now

Answer (score 0):

Trying to create a decimal fraction number to represent months makes no sense to me, as months have different numbers of days (28, 29, 30, 31).

## ISO 8601

The sensible [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines a textual way to represent a span of time in terms of months and days, called [Durations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) has a class for this purpose called [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html). Forgive the mismatch in terms, as there is no standard definition of date-time terminology yet.

For an example of using the Period class, see [this other answer by Ilya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23965740/642706) on this question.

## ISO Duration

The textual format is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` means "Period" and the `T` separates the date portion from time portion. The other parts are optional. One month and two days would be `P1M2D`. The Joda-Time Period class both parses and generates such strings.